# Spring pass model from POST

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, post-redirect-get

I'm quite knowledgeable with Spring yet. I'm trying to learn. Please help me quite a bit.

I have a form which uses `modelAttribute="projectBean"` which is working perfectly fine and I'm able to manipulate data on the controller below

```
@RequestMapping( value = "projects/newProject", method = RequestMethod.POST )
public String newProject( @ModelAttribute( "projectBean" )
ProjectBean projectBean, HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model )
{

    model.addAttribute( "projectBean", projectBean );

    return "redirect:../projects/projectItems.do";
}
```

I'm done saving it to the database so I want now to pass the `projectBean` to another controller

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/projects/projectItems", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public String projectItems( @RequestParam( defaultValue = "" )
String message, @RequestParam( defaultValue = "" )
String messageType, @RequestParam( defaultValue = "" )
String projectID, HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam( "projectBean" )
ProjectBean projectBean, ModelMap model )
{

    return "project/items";
}
```

But i'm having this exception: `Required ProjectBean parameter 'projectBean' is not present`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to pass it to another controller? Are you trying to pass it to another JSP page?

Comment: use  @ModelAttribute( "projectBean" ) ProjectBean projectBean in projectItems .. Why @RequestParam( ?

Comment: @pramod.nikam.dev why `@ModelAttribute` works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't generally pass a model from one Controller to another Controller. I assume you are trying to perform some logic before passing the model to another JSP page (`project/items` in this case).

You can achieve the same in `newProject()` controller rather than trying to pass the model to another Controller

```
@RequestMapping( value = "projects/newProject", method = RequestMethod.POST )
public String newProject( @ModelAttribute( "projectBean" )
ProjectBean projectBean, HttpServletRequest request, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)
{

    //Call DAO class to save the model to database

    //Call BusinessDelegate class to perform the additional logic

    //Add beans to RedirectAttributes using addFlashAttribute() methods to make it available in next JSP page
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("projectBean", projectBean);

    return "redirect:/project/items";
}
```

**Note:** In order to apply POST-REDIRECT-GET pattern, you should use `RedirectAttributes` instead of `ModelMap` to make the model attributes available in redirected JSP page.

Comment: if you refresh the page it will again insert the data in the database if I do it this way.

Comment: I missed that point. Thanks. I updated the answer with relevant code which should work for you. Please verify.

Comment: Sorry but can you guide me a bit more. I'm really noob with Spring. I tried `flashAttribute` but I get this error. `Argument [RedirectAttributes] is of type Model or Map but is not assignable from the actual model. You may need to switch newer MVC infrastructure classes to use this argument.` Is there something I need to configure before I can use this approach?

Comment: What I lack is this `mvc:annotation-driven` I just added this to my `webapp-servlet.xml` and it works